# Java Lambda function feeding with extend type

Tags: java, recursion, inheritance, lambda, extends

Eclipse is telling me that this:

```
interface Recursive
{
    List<? extends Recursive> getSubitems();

    default void processRecursive(Consumer<? extends Recursive> f)
    {
        f.accept(this);
        for (Recursive r : getSubitems())
            f.accept(r);
    }
}
```

is not possible (Error for f.accept(this) and f.accept(r) : The method accept(capture#1-of ? extends Recursive) in the type Consumer is not applicable for the arguments (Recursive))

I am wondering why, since this will extends Recursive, so will r (a recursive), and they can be processed as Recursives..

It seems to me that this would be perfectly reasonable and predictable behavior.

Comment: I could, but then, if we had say a leaf object extending recursive, with a list of leaf objects within it, we would have to store them as a list of Recusive and cast them every time to e.g. access its values making it a lot more painful to work with. Hence a list of a subtype of recursive would be of more use and should, as far as I see it, work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have two classes implementing the interface: `Foo` and `Bar`

```
Consumer<Bar> barConsumer = ...

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.processRecursive(barConsumer);
```

Now, according to the method signature, that `processRecursive()` call is valid, because `barConsumer` fits `Consumer<? extends Recursive>`.

However, the code `f.accept(this)` would violate the `Consumer<Bar>` by trying to send a `Foo` object to the `Comsumer`. That's why the compiler complains, because it cannot guarantee type-safety, i.e. that only valid objects are given to the `accept()` method.

Since there is no way to enforce that `this` is the correct subtype of `Recursive`, there is no *type-safe* way to do this.

If you're ok with sacrificing *some* type-safety, you can make `Recursive` a generic:

```
interface Recursive<T extends Recursive> {
    List<T> getSubitems();

    default void processRecursive(Consumer<T> consumer) {
        consumer.accept((T) this); // sacrificing type-safety
        for (T item : getSubitems())
            consumer.accept(item);
    }
}
```

Now it can be used like, and all is good with the world:

```
class Foo implements Recursive<Foo> {
```

But someone could write this, breaking the code, because now `this` is not a `Bar`, so the cast will throw exception at runtime *(maybe, depends on Java version I believe)*:

```
class Foo implements Recursive<Bar> {
```

Comment: Okay makes sense now, is there a way to enforce the consumer to extend "this.getClass()"?